# Cucumber on Travis CI container

Tags: docker, cucumber, travis-ci

I am trying to get [Cucumber](https://cucumber.io/) to run tests on my [builds](https://github.com/jpsecher/travis) on [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org/) with following minimal `.travis.yml`:

```
language: ruby
sudo: required
services: docker
before_install:
  - sudo apt-get update -qq
  - sudo apt-get install -qq cucumber
script:
  - cucumber --version
```

But the build fails with

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- cucumber/rspec/disable_option_parser (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /usr/bin/cucumber:10:in `<main>'
```

Do I need to install other packages than cucumber?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems all the packages are being installed, the problem here I think is that `sudo apt-get install -qq cucumber` installed ruby 1.9.3 and then cucumber (check the log), calling `cucumber` tries to execute using ruby 2.2 (travis default)

Maybe you should stick to using bundler or rake to install the cuke.

Comment: Thanks, `before_script: gem install cucumber` instead of `apt-get`ting does the trick.